# Hadoop - Example MapReduce Application not running

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I deployed Hadoop 2.2.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS according this article: http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1

Everything is OK except when I try to run Hadoop example at last step, it's pause with message Job Running

```
13/11/24 23:36:30 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
13/11/24 23:36:30 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
13/11/24 23:36:31 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1385310900376_0001
13/11/24 23:36:32 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1385310900376_0001 to ResourceManager at master/192.168.56.1:8040
13/11/24 23:36:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1385310900376_0001/
13/11/24 23:36:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1385310900376_0001
```

In ResourceManager Web GUI, i see "App is Pending". So, how I can change to Running State?

Screenshot: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7344/11031415055_d987e937aa_o.png

Thanks you! :)

Comment: can you post the code of mapper reducer and driver?

Comment: @sonic I run 2 example MapReduce apps are WordCount and Estimates Pi :)